# Android Application Force Close error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wrote the following code and compiled it but when I run the application, I get the error **android the application has stopped unexpectedly force close eclipse**. I thought this is because I didn't initialize the Button and TextView objects but when I initialize them, I get missing token ";" error. What is the reason for this error.

```
package com.umer.first.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

int counter;
TextView display;
Button add, sub;
//add= new Button(this);
//sub=new Button(this);
//display=new TextView();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

    add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.aButton);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sButton);
    display= (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvButton);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("The total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            counter--;
            display.setText("You counter is " + counter);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_starting_point, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: you did not initialized the counter but you do counter++/-- which is not defined.

Comment: arent `int` in java initialised to `0` by default?

Comment: primitive types are initialized to zero automatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Display` is a `TextView`, you can't cast it to a button.

```
display= (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvButton);
```

Comment: Why don't we need to initialize the button and textview objects? There are initialized to NULL according to Java if they are not explicitly initialized?

Comment: Yes when you define `private TextView display` it can be consider as NULL and then you initialize it with `display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvbutton)`

Comment: And this syntax "sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()" here inside the argument parenthesis, new ----- syntax is used to initialize an object but we are calling a static function of view class, What is this syntax doing and what does it mean

Comment: It is used when a **view** is clicked : [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Comment: I know that. I asked, don't we use new to initialze objects? Not while calling a method of a class

Comment: Actually We initialize a new class. We can write it in this way also: `sb.setOnClickListener(new Click());` And then create a new class: `private class Click implements View.OnClickListener` You need to implement `public void onClick(View v)` inside the class. I also suggest you to research on your own.

Answer (score 0):

**2.** You have **declared** `display` **as TextView**,but **initialized as** `Button`, **thats a Casting Exception** .

`display= (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvButton);`     ///// Wrong.

Must be.

`display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvButton);`

**1.** Do the **declaration of the Views as instance variables before onCreate()** Method, then **initialize them in the onCreate().**